# rvm resetting the default

Tags: ruby, rvm

These are the rubies I have installed with RVM

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-head [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-rc1 [ x86_64 ]
```

I have a lot of gemsets for 1.9.2

```
gemsets for ruby-1.9.2-p290 (found in /Users/mm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290)
   19332
   309
   clone
   devise
   devise311
   enki
   global
   rails3
   rails301
   rails303
   rails304
   rails310
   rails313
   rails32
   rails323
   rails3tutorial
   railsValim
```

However, when I tried to use one of them, it said it didn't exist

```
rvm use 1.9.2@rails304
ERROR: Gemset 'rails304' does not exist, rvm gemset create 'rails304' first.
WARN: Gemset doesn't exist, proceeding with default gemset
WARN: ruby ruby-1.9.2-use1.9.2 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.2-use1.9.2'
```

Please notice the reference to the version of Ruby in the last line

```
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.2-use1.9.2'
```

This is different than the ruby listed above

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
```

I don't know where the Ruby with 'use1.9.2' at the end came from. Maybe I screwed up somehow by trying to do something like `rvm use 1.9.2` so the word 'use' got stuck together with 1.9.2., so I tried to set the other rvm ruby (p290) as the default

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290 --default
Using /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
```

but when I did that and tried to use one of its gemsets, it said it didn't exist

```
rvm use 1.9.2@rails304
ERROR: Gemset 'rails304' does not exist, rvm gemset create 'rails304' first.
WARN: Gemset doesn't exist, proceeding with default gemset
WARN: ruby ruby-1.9.2-use1.9.2 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.2-use1.9.2'
```

and again, it had reference to this other ruby version 'ruby-1.9.2-use.1.9.2' with that funny 'use.1.9.2' on the end.

I don't know if this is my human error, or something that's resulting from my recent installation of Mountain Lion, which caused some other system changes on my computer.

How would I go about getting 'ruby-1.9.2-use.1.9.2' off my system and using the ruby 1.9.2 listed when I do the command `rvm rubies`

```
       ruby-1.8.7-head [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
       ruby-1.9.3-rc1 [ x86_64 ]
```

Comment: First select **rvm use 1.9.2** than **rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails304** . It will work. I think you forgot to select rvm use ruby version.

Comment: doesn't work. when I do 'rvm use 1.9.2' it refers to that other version of 1.9.2. that's not even listed as one of the rubies. Here's the error message:  , WARN: ruby ruby-1.9.2-use1.9.2 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.2-use1.9.2'

Comment: It's supposed to be  "ruby-1.9.2-p290" according to the rvm rubies, but when I do rvm use 1.9.2. it's looking for some mysterious "ruby-1.9.2-use1.9.2'"

Comment: did you try like this **rvm gemset use rails304** after selecting the **rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290**?

Comment: ok, thanks, that was the problem, I didn't use the word 'gemset' in the command, rvm gemset use rails304.

Comment: You know the first comment is also working fine if you install rvm and ruby properly . check the commands in this link http://www.extendedcode.com/how-to-use-rvm-basic-commands-29

Comment: what version of rvm is this? your steps should work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know why synonym "rvm use 1.9.2" stop working and shows such a strange behavior but
assuming using the exact name of rubie work, you can try to specify gemset like this

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails304
```

or to setup as default

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails304 --default
```

Comment: Please add additional clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some information for understanding the behavior of `rvm use`

When you run `rvm list known` it will list rubies in the following format:

```
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.3-p125
[ruby-]1.9.3-p194
[ruby-]1.9.3-p286
[ruby-]1.9.3-p327
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p362]
```

The parts contained in [] are optional to type in. Therefore, doing `rvm use 1.9.3` would attempt to use 1.9.3-p362 as it is considered the best 1.9.3 version to use. If you don't have it installed, it will ask you to install it first. That means, when you installed ruby-1.9.2 it probably installed p290 as it was the latest version and that is no longer the case after upgrading RVM to a newer version. Therefore, to use your gemsets for the version you have installed, you need to do `rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290@GEMSET`.